# Cat and cat piped together

Tags: sh, cat

Let's consider:

```
cat | cat
```

Which one read from `stdin` terminal and which one write to `stdout` terminal and why?

And especially, how does it works:

```
cat < uns2.txt > ss2.txt | sort
```

I cannot understand what is more important: `>` vs `|`

Comment: `cat` by itself reads from `stdin` and outputs to `stdout`. The `|` of the first `cat` means the `stdout` is routed to the `stdin` of the next command (which is `cat`). So the first `cat` reads from the `stdin` (user), outputs to `stdout` which goes through the pipe to `stdin` of the second `cat`, which sends it's output to `stdout` (user).

Comment: Have you read any Unix shell documentation? These are basic Unix shell principles that should be in any common shell explanatory text.

Comment: but, try run it! and see that it works currently. I can't get it. Perhaps, only one process can be controlled by shell ( I skipped case of & )

Comment: I tried it. It works as I would expect. `cat | cat` should behave just like `cat` all by itself. (1) I enter `cat | cat`, (2) I type "foo" <cr>, (3) it echoes back "foo"<cr> (4) I type ctrl-D, (5) program exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each program chooses how to interpret its arguments.  Like many Unix utilities, **cat** is written as a filter; in the absence of filenames on the command line, it reads from standard input and writes to standard output.  That makes it more convenient than e.g. **tr**, which *only* reads from standard input.

> I cannot understand what is more important: > vs |

Now we are talking about what the shell does, not the program it's invoking.  Without redirection, the shell attaches standard input and output (and error) to the terminal.  Redirection, well, *redirects* things.

With `<`, the shell opens the file named to the right, and substitutes that descriptor for standard input.  With `|`, the shell creates a pipe, and replaces the standard output of the program to the left with the write end of the pipe, and the standard input of the program to the right with read end of the pipe.  The invoked program (e.g. **cat**) continues to "write to stdout"; the shell has simply changed what "stdout" means.

With that information, you can answer your own question: the `|` between the cats redirects the output of the left side to the input of the right.  the first **cat** continues to read from standard input, and the second cat continues to write to standard output.

As mentioned in the comments, a book on the Unix shell would probably be useful to you.  You can't learn this sort of thing one question at a time.